# Unity Container: Difference between constructor vs property vs method injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

This is specific to Unity DI.

It seems common wisdom states that if the majority of your class requires a certain dependency then you should use constructor injection. If the dependency is only needed in a subset of use cases for the class then you should use property injection (or possibly method injection). I assumed this was because the latter two don't resolve the object until they're referenced, but in my experience all three of these resolve the dependencies on object creation, so what is the utility of using one over the other?

Also, [the Unity documentation on deferring object creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn507482(v=pandp.30)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) only mentions the Lazy<> and Func<> generics.

1. Is there a way to set up property and/or method injection to defer resolution?
2. If not, are there different methods just to allow for stylistic preferences?

Comment: Why does not Lazy<> work for you? It should defer the object instantiation and the resolution of its dependencies until you call its value getter. Could you provide some short code on which you could demonstrate what you want to achieve?

Comment: Lazy<> does work, I was just curious why there were different methods for injection if they're functionally identical when it comes to dependency resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, basically deferring resolution using properties is a bad practice. Some DI containers (Microsoft.Extensions.* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) does not even allow you to do that.

If your code followed SOLID principles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), the need to defer resolution would almost never occur. Instead, you should split your classes into smaller pieces and each would inject through its constructor. If you still need to defer the resolution (e.g., when you create a facade), you can inject an abstract factory and called its factory method to instantiate instance when you need it.

Comment: I appreciate then insight. The object in question is an api controller and one route on it requires a service that is very expensive to resolve. That route could possibly belong in it's own controller.  As to the question in my post, do you know why Unity offers three different injection strategies that all resolve the dependencies on object creation? What would motivate you to use one over the other?

Comment: Using property injection is in Unity, perhaps because many people are used to it from java Spring, and it can make your code shorter. However, many argue that it causes the code to be prone to runtime errors. The same holds for method injection. If you want to derive a base class with complex constructor, but want your code to be short and less prone to the change of interface, you can decide to use the property injection if the assignment is trivial and method injection if it is nontrivial. Still, I would prefer not to use it in any larger codebase.